# recognizing if a string as the same format as a car plate[portugal]

Tags: c#, .net

i don't know how to check if a string as a format of a car plate
exemple.**76-AR-33**
if detected it would thrown a exception

Comment: I would suggest you to start looking into regular expressions for solving the problem in hand.
One of the use cases for regular expressions is, you can define a desired pattern and then match user inputs against the pattern. The following link can serve as a good starting point: [Regular expressions in C#](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_regular_expressions.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, note that along the time, the format have changed, and probably will change again.
Also there is special vehicles with different format car plates. Current format can be tested with a regular expression:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;



if (Regex.IsMatch(carPlate, @"\d{2}-[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) { 
  Console.Write("carPlate is valid");
}
```

Let see each part of the regex

- \d means match any digit
- [a-z] means match any letter (no tilde letters, only from a to z)
- {} brackets allow specify the number of ocurrences of the matched symbol, in ths case 2

You can test your regex in any of the regex online pages, for example:
https://regexr.com/

You can know more about regEx at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: it is case sensitive ?

Comment: With the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option, the search is case insensitive